# jQuery - Attach POST data to a submit() call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

In pretty new to the jQuery scene.

What have is a form like so

```
<form method="POST" action="/ajax/controller.php" id="exportform">
```

Inside the form i have a text input

```
<input id="name" name="name" />
```

Then i have a bit os jQuery that submits the form

```
$("#save").click(function() {
    $("#exportform").submit();
});
```

My question is, how do i go about submitting a JS array via POST data to that controller when the save button is clicked and also keep the post value from the input field

As i have the submit() function already there, does that mean i cant use the $.post() .... Im quite confused how to go about this

Comment: so your intention is to submit the form without reloading the page to keep the inputs? just use `$.post();/$.ajax();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the post from your html :

```
<form id="exportform">
```

and send the data with AJAX :

```
$("#save").click(function() {
     $.post( "/ajax/controller.php", function( data ) {
         $( ".result" ).html( data );
     });
});
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense ... and i can access all the post data in my controller using $_POST ... that makes sense ... Thank you, i will try that

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#exportform").submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/controller.php",
    data: {name: $("#name").val()}
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> My question is, how do i go about submitting a JS array via POST data
>   to that controller when the save button is clicked and also keep the
>   post value from the input field

you can make your POST request into data:JSON and format your array into JSON and read or decode the JSON in the server side.

> As i have the submit() function already there, does that mean i cant
>   use the $.post() .... Im quite confused how to go about this

i doubt if you used the submit method you cant use ajax.

Comment: datatype:JSON describes the server response

Comment: oh my bad it should be data:JSON

Comment: nope, data: is what you send to the server, you don't specify its type

Comment: yes it is. but what im saying is the content of data should be JSON so that he can pass the value of the array into the server side.

        `var data = {
           data_req: []   //now this is your array
        };

        data.data_req.push({
            0:"dummy data"
        })`

now he can push this into ajax like 

`$.post(url,data:data,function(response){
   //do whatever you like with the response
})`